# Sending mail in python with attachment sent it multiply times

Tags: python, email, gmail

Am sending mail in python with attachment, the mail is sent alright but it sent as three different mail with the attachment in each mail .

How can i make so that all the file will be one mail.

```
filename = ['GIG.JPG', "facebook.png", "cld.png"]

for n in filename:
    print(n)
    attachment = open(str(n), 'rb')

    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= " + n)

    msg.attach(part)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(FROMADDR, PASSWORD)

    server.sendmail(FROMADDR, TOADDR + CCADDR, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail Python multiple attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582811/gmail-python-multiple-attachments)

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating through the filename array which contains 3 items, so mail is going three times.

Do something like this

```
 from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

 for file in filename:
 # Open the files in binary mode.  Let the MIMEImage class automatically
 # guess the specific image type.
     with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
         img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
     msg.attach(img)
```

This might work in your case.

Comment: how will i import `MIMEImage`

Comment: Added the import to answer.