# How to attach multiple files to email?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, email-attachments, smtplib

I am using the following modules to send emails using python:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import email, smtplib, ssl
```

I want to send multiple attachments but for some reason they are not attaching? The program returns no errors.

This is the part of the program which takes a tuple of file paths to attach to the email. Why does this not work and how can I make it work?

```
for file in filelist:
    with open(file, "rb") as attachment:
        attachment_part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
        attachment_part.set_payload(attachment.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(attachment_part)
        attachment_part.add_header(
            "Content-Disposition",
            f"attachment; filename = {filename}",
        )
        message.attach(attachment_part)

    # Create Server Connection
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
        server.login(config.email_sender, config.email_password)
        server.sendmail(
            sender_email, reciever_email, message.as_string()
        )
```

Happy to provide more details...

EDIT:

I have tried to use what other questions have but I am not getting any attachment. I am not getting any errors either...

EDIT 2:

```
for file in filelist:
            attachment_part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
            attachment_part.set_payload(open(file, "rb").read())
            encoders.encode_base64(attachment_part)
            attachment_part.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='%s'" % os.path.basename(file))
            message.attach(attachment_part)

# Create Server Connection
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
            server.login(config.email_sender, config.email_password)
            server.sendmail(
                sender_email, reciever_email, message.as_string()
            )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gmail Python multiple attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582811/gmail-python-multiple-attachments)

Comment: No. It doesn't attach the files, it doesn't give errors either.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the problem was ultimately caused by code not shown in the question which caused `filelist` to be empty. But the code initially shown in the question was wrong too. Original answer kept for this reason.

---

In your code you have this:

```
for file in filelist:
    with open(file, "rb") as attachment:
        ...
        message.attach(attachment_part)

    # Create Server Connection
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
        ...
```

Your indentation and therefore your program logic is messaged up in this code. Instead of first creating the message, attaching all files and then sending the message you'll send a new message every time you've attached a file.

What you do need to do instead is move the sending of the mail out of the loop over the filelist:

```
for file in filelist:
    with open(file, "rb") as attachment:
        ...
        message.attach(attachment_part)

# Create Server Connection
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
   ...
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting You are posing pretty much the same code?

Comment: @KevinApetrei: sorry, I thought it was obvious what you need to fix based on the explanation. But I've added it explicitly to the answer now.

Comment: I've changed the code to this: ```for file in filelist:
            attachment_part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
            attachment_part.set_payload(open(file, "rb").read())
            encoders.encode_base64(attachment_part)
            attachment_part.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='%s'" % os.path.basename(file))
            message.attach(attachment_part)``` But it still does nothing. No errors and no attachment...

Comment: @KevinApetrei: it is impossible to say based on your comment how your code currently looks like, because line ends and indentation is relevant with Python but not preserved in your comment. But since you did not seem to change the indentation for the mail sending part and thus did not seem to address the problem I've pointed out.

Comment: @KevinApetrei: to reiterate: *"But since __you did not seem to change the indentation for the mail sending part__ and thus did not seem to address the problem I've pointed out. "*. Apart from that the formatting in the question now seems to be totally messed up.

Comment: The formatting is messed up on my program it looks fine. The `for` and `with` are on the same indentation level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220242/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-kevin-apetrei).

Comment: if someone have same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64947133/6007952

Answer (score 0):

My function within my main function which was picking the files and putting the paths into a list was not globalised.

However, for some reason, it was not giving me any errors.